# Why does Raster Calculator (RasterCalculator_sa) give ERROR 000539 in ArcPy?

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.2, spatial-analyst, raster-calculator, error-000539

I am getting a not executed error for a raster calculator.   Here is part of the output:

> File "C:\projectTemp\FloodAnalysis\floodxsectionanalysis.py", line
>   107, in makeSeemless
>            arcpy.gp.RasterCalculator_sa(Con(IsNull(rasterIn), FocalStatistics(rasterIn,NbrRectangle(3, 3), "MEAN"), rasterIn),
>   "{0}yrSeemless.img".format(increment))   File "C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\ArcGIS\Desktop10.2\arcpy\arcpy\geoprocessing_base.py", line
>   498, in 
>       return lambda *args: val(*gp_fixargs(args, True)) arcgisscripting.ExecuteError: ERROR 000539: Parsing error SyntaxError:
>   invalid syntax (line 5) Failed to execute (RasterCalculator).

This code I have setup to put into this calculator is:

```
def makeSeemless(outputPath, increment, rasterIn):
    arcpy.gp.RasterCalculator_sa(Con(IsNull(rasterIn), FocalStatistics(rasterIn,NbrRectangle(3, 3), "MEAN"), rasterIn), "{0}yrSeemless.img".format(increment))
```

Comment: in python you should use the map algebra module : see http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//00p600000002000000

Comment: Is the syntax the same?

Comment: Yeah, I was wrestling with the textbox..  I fixed it. Slightly different way of writing in the same function.  Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From the [ArcGIS Help](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//009z000000z7000000):

> Note: The Raster Calculator tool is intended for use in the ArcGIS for
>   Desktop application only as a GP tool dialog box or in ModelBuilder.
>   It is not intended for use in scripting and is not available in the
>   ArcPy Spatial Analyst module.

That said, you *can* use it with `arcpy.gp.RasterCalculator_sa`, but you need to pass it a string expression, i.e. `arcpy.gp.RasterCalculator_sa('Con(IsNull("somerasterlayer"), etc...)')`

As suggested by @radouxju, you're better off using the [map algebra](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//00p600000002000000) syntax instead:

```
import arcview,arcpy
from arcpy.sa import *
rasterIn=Raster('path to raster')
rasterOut=Con(IsNull(rasterIn), FocalStatistics(rasterIn,NbrRectangle(3, 3), "MEAN"), rasterIn)
rasterOut.save("{0}yrSeemless.img".format(increment))
```