# Automating Raster Calculator

Tags: arcgis-desktop, python, arcpy, raster-calculator, map-algebra

I am seeing mixed answers on other posts so I thought I would ask here.  Is there a way to automate the raster calculator?

I am trying to create a series of inundation maps at fine increments.  It is tedious to do manually, so I would like to write a script that will loop the raster calculator.

Comment: Is there anything on this thread that doesn't answer your question? http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/84887/why-does-raster-calculator-rastercalculator-sa-give-error-000539-in-arcpy

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE. Please mention the software that you are using

Comment: For Qgis : http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/54949/how-to-evaluate-raster-calculator-expressions-from-the-console

Comment: Could you please supply the type of calculations you are performing?

Comment: I am using ArcMap 10.1

Comment: the calculation is DEM cells < specified elevation

Comment: Are you looking to apply a binary threshold on the DEM values, where the output would be, for example, 0 for values below 500m and 1 for values >= 500?

Comment: Yes. I am looking a watershed in south Florida where topographic variations are subtle so I want to create a series of layers in increments of 0.1 ft or less.

Comment: If you have already reviewed near duplicates I think it is worth including links to them to explain why you think your question is different.

Comment: Don't use the raster calculator in a script, use arcpy.sa (spatial analyst) [syntax](http://gis.stackexchange.com/a/84895/2856) instead. If you want to batch the raster calculator, instead of opening it, right click on the tool and select Batch... another alternative is to add the tool to a model. If either of the batch or model methods sound like they might be what you need then give them a go and then edit your question to provide further information about where you are having trouble. Otherwise your question is likely to be closed as a duplicate.